# Is there any direct relational equation between temperature and power?

Tags: cloud, temperature, energy

I am working on reducing power consumption of hosts in cloud computing. For this, I need to know the temperature of my host's CPU. I would like to derive the temperature from the power the CPU host is consuming that moment. Since I've no clear idea on thermodynamic, I am confused if I can do so. Can I get any help or suggestion about theories and formulas of Power, Temperature and Energy that can help me to reach my goal?

Comment: This probably belongs on Physics or Server Fault. Not sure which.

Comment: Measuring power/energy/temperature is a big and important data center problem. That means that there are a lot of companies offering packages for doing this. Check around. One such product that is "free", is the [Intel Energy Checker](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-energy-checker-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't derive temperature from power. You might want to review first-year physics, if you have the time.

Long answer:
You will need more information than just the power. **Energy** is conserved; that is, energy is not created or destroyed, it just moves around and changes form. Electrical energy enters the computer through a cord, and the *rate* at which it enters is called the **power**. But that energy has to go somewhere, it can't be destroyed. If the computer has a battery, some energy can accumulate there, but only until the battery is full. If the computer has lights, it can radiate some energy as light. If it has a printer, it can expend some energy lifting paper from a low tray to a high hopper. It can invest a *tiny* amount of energy into storing information in a magnetic medium. But basically all the energy that goes into the machine comes out in the easiest form, **heat**.

The machine can shed heat with radiator fins, or by warming the air in the room. If it can't shed heat fast enough, the heat will accumulate, and as a result the temperature of the machine will rise. The hotter the machine gets, the more quickly it can shed heat (because a hot thing warms the air faster than a warm thing). One way or another, the machine will reach equilibrium, so that the rate at which it sheds heat energy will match the rate at which it consumes electrical energy (apart from the small expenditures mentioned above).

So what will that equilibrium temperature be? It depends on other factors. A machine with a really good cooling system in a cold room can consume 1000W and say nice and cool; a machine with a weak fan stuck in a stuffy closet in the middle of summer with a lot of other such machines can get hot enough to fry an egg even when it's in sleep mode consuming 3.5W.

You'll need more information. Maybe you can get the client to mount a thermometer in the server room.